# Java myInput.readLine error

Tags: java

When I compile my program, I get an error saying,

cannot find symbol

symbol  : variable myInput

location: class diceGame

I've looked over my code and can't seem to find the error in the read line. What does it mean? Why is this error occurring?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class diceGame
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    pairOfDice dice;

    dice = new pairOfDice();

    playerGame player;

    player = new playerGame();

    int rollCount = 0;

    int holdB = 0;
    do {
      dice.roll();    // Roll the first pair of dice.
      System.out.println("Dice 1: " + dice.getDiceA() + "\n" + "Dice 2: " + dice.getDiceB() + "\n" + "The total is: " + dice.getTotal());
      System.out.println("Do you want to hold the value of the dice? Press 0 to hold none/ 1 to hold die 1/ 2 to hold die 2/ 3 to hold both");
      String hold = myInput.readLine();
      int holdA = Integer.parseInt(hold);
      if (holdA == 0){
      }
      if (holdA == 1){
        player.getHoldA();
        player.setHoldA(dice.getDiceA());
        System.out.println("Value of dice A is held");
      }
      if (holdA == 2){
        player.setHoldB(dice.getDiceB());
        System.out.println("Value of dice B is held");
      }
      if (holdA == 3){
        player.setHoldA(dice.getDiceA());
        System.out.println("Value of dice A is held");
        player.setHoldB(dice.getDiceB());
        System.out.println("Value of dice B is held");
        break;
      }
      rollCount++;
    }
    while (dice.getTurns() <= 3);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that on this line:

```
String hold = myInput.readLine();
```

It doesn't know what `myInput` is, since you never defined it.

Most likely you want to add a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) around [`System.in`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in), then read from that:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String nextLine = input.readLine();
```